# Failing to Retrieve Toggled State as 0 or 1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, toggle

Hey I just started working on Toggle Buttons and I have set the properties of the button. I want to check for the toggle state which should return me 1 or 0.

**XAML:**

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Content="On" Command="{Binding VoltageToggleCommand}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Name="VoltageToggleBtn" />
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
private ICommand mToggleButtonCommand;
    public ICommand VoltageToggleCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mToggleButtonCommand == null)
                mToggleButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(ToggleButtonCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(ToggleButtonCommandCanExecute));

            return mToggleButtonCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mToggleButtonCommand = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for ToggleButton State
    /// </summary>
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return this.isChecked; }
        set
        {
            this.isChecked = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    public bool ToggleButtonCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ToggleButtonCommandExecuted()
    {
        Byte[] cmdArray = new Byte[256];
        int numBytes = 0;
        cmdArray[numBytes++] = // Here I wanna retrieve the toggle state i.e. 1 or 0
        // Some Code
    }
```

Thus when I click the toggle button, controls reaches `ToggleButtonCommandExecuted()` where I need to check for the state and store it in `cmdArray`. Basically when code is executed cmdArray[numBytes++] = 1 or 0.

How can I achieve it? :)

Comment: Is there a reason ou're using `byte` instead of `bool` for your array?

Comment: @DanPuzey: Yes the statements which I need to execute later require this value in the form of BYTE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to convert from boolean to byte yourself

```
cmdArray[numBytes++] = (byte)(IsChecked ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: I did this: cmdArray[numBytes++] = Convert.ToByte(IsChecked ? 1 : 0);

Comment: @StonedJesus Not that much of a difference. The main point is you need to translate true/false to a number and then make sure the number is a byte

Answer (score 1):

Use the [if short form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
IsChecked ? 1: 0
```

Comment: you will have to convert to byte. Can't explicitly convert to a smaller value type

Comment: and that should have said you can't do it implicitly but have to do it explicitly (due to the potential lack of informaiton)